# What is the way of creating custom Reactive attribute?

Tags: c#, reflection, mono, .net-assembly, reactive

I work with Reactive UI library for my WPF applications and was curious about how does the *[Reactive]* attribute work. I found out that there is nothing there in the attribute itself so there was a lot of questions about the actual work of it. Then I found the piece of code that loads current assembly (using *Mono.Cecil* and *Fody* libraries), finds all classes that extend *ReactiveObject* class and searches there for *[Reactive]* attributes ([original source](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/main/src/ReactiveUI.Fody/ReactiveUIPropertyWeaver.cs)):

```cs
var reactiveObject = new TypeReference("ReactiveUI", "IReactiveObject", ModuleDefinition, reactiveUI);
var targetTypes = ModuleDefinition.GetAllTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType is not null && reactiveObject.IsAssignableFrom(x.BaseType)).ToArray();
var reactiveObjectExtensions = new TypeReference("ReactiveUI", "IReactiveObjectExtensions", ModuleDefinition, reactiveUI).Resolve() ?? throw new Exception("reactiveObjectExtensions is null");
var raiseAndSetIfChangedMethod = ModuleDefinition.ImportReference(reactiveObjectExtensions.Methods.Single(x => x.Name == "RaiseAndSetIfChanged")) ?? throw new Exception("raiseAndSetIfChangedMethod is null");
var reactiveAttribute = ModuleDefinition.FindType("ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers", "ReactiveAttribute", helpers) ?? throw new Exception("reactiveAttribute is null");
```

Then is creates private field for each property and binds a method (that calls *PropertyChanged* event).
Everything was quite clear so I decided to create my own attribute and property resolver for the attribute but now I have an obvious problem. When the resolver changes the IL code - it should rewrite the current assembly (as I understand)). I don't know much about prebuilds and postbuild things but I think that this things should be done not in the already running assembly but somewhere in prebuild actions. Here is the code I actually wrote (it crushes on the `module.Write(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);` line (quite obvious cause the current assembly file is locked)):

```cs
var module = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
var reactiveResolver = new ReactivePropertyResolver()
{
    ModuleDefinition = module,
};
reactiveResolver.Execute();
module.Write(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
module?.Dispose();
```

I changed almoust nothing in the *ReactivePropertyResolver*, only some namespaces and other small things.

So the main question is - Whereand how should I do all this stuff to get it work?

(I've already asked the question on Software Engineering SE but got downvoted - quite curious :/ )

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after all this time a can tell you that is the easiest way of creating custom attribute is to use [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody). Firstly I found a library called PostSharp but it is not free. Then I tried to use pure *Mono.Cecil* (as you can see in the question) but gave up with MSBuild crazy things. Probably I'm too stupid for these things like *AfterBuild* commands and etc.
I didn't want to use *Fody* because of it's configuration *.xml* and *.xsd* files that should be on top of your project structure. But now it's ok for me and maybe I can rid of them (should test it).
And the final answer for now and for me is [the repo](https://github.com/CrackAndDie/Abdrakov.Fody) that I created based on these repos - [PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged), [ReactiveUI](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI), [MethodBoundaryAspectFody](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody/tree/master).